# How to run and access web server running inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have trouble understanding how Docker handle things.

I am trying to run a node web server for development purpose. I have it defined in a docker-compose.yml and everything works fine when i run it from there. But when i manually run it from inside the container, it can't be reach from outside.

e.g : this is working fine

```
node:
        image: node:10.15-stretch
        tty: true
        command: bash -c "./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --public http://dev.local:8080 --port 8080 --disable-host-check --hot"
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}:/var/www/
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

The files are now accessible from http://dev.local:8080 !

But i would prefer run it manually only when i need it...
So i remove the command from the docker-compose.yml and run it from inside the container :

```
node:
        image: node:10.15-stretch
        tty: true
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}:/var/www/
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

```
docker-compose run node bash
```

```
root@1535e3c963cc:/var/www/# ./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --public http://dev.local:8080 --port 8080 --disable-host-check --hot
```

The process is running fine but the files are **not** accessible from http://dev.local:8080 ...

I am sure there is something i am missing from Docker but i can't find what...

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
here the full config

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        image: httpd
        volumes:
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}/.docker/conf/apache/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}/.docker/conf/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}:/var/www/sadc/alarm
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
            - postgres

    php:
        build: .docker
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        volumes:
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}/.docker/conf/php/php.ini:/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}/.docker/conf/php/php.ini:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}:/var/www/sadc/alarm
        environment:
            - PGDATESTYLE=ISO,DMY
        working_dir: /var/www/sadc/alarm


    postgres:
        image: mdillon/postgis:10
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=${PG_DATABASE}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${PG_USERNAME}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PG_PASSWORD}
            - PGDATESTYLE=ISO,DMY
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - sadc-alarm-pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}:/var/www/sadc/alarm
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}/.docker/conf/postgres/initdb.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sql

    node:
        image: node:10.15-stretch
        tty: true
        working_dir: /var/www/sadc/alarm
        volumes:
            - ${PATH_SOURCE}:/var/www/sadc/alarm
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
c6a394453de4        node:10.15-stretch   "node"                   2 hours ago         Up 50 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                     alarm_node_1     
5dcc8b936b58        httpd                "httpd-foreground"       21 hours ago        Up 49 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   alarm_apache_1   
bb616453d0cc        alarm_php            "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   21 hours ago        Up 49 seconds       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                     alarm_php_1      
3af75f3a3716        mdillon/postgis:10   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   28 hours ago        Up 49 seconds       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```

**EDIT 2**

Problem is with "docker-compose run" method...

When i run the following using "docker exec" it works

`docker exec -it node_alarm_1 bash`

**FINAL EDIT**

OK.

So i missused "docker-compose run" method. It is "docker-compose exec" method that should be use because it's reuse the running container that is correctly mapped. "docker-compose run" instead run a non-mapped container...

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose run` it doesn't seem to respect port publishing described in `docker-compose.yml` file.

To fix your issue do the following

```
docker-compose run -p 8080:8080 node bash
```

or

```
docker-compose run --service-ports node bash
```

Comment: Both return "Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated"

Comment: Are you already running something on port 8080? Make sure to stop your apps that use port 8080.

Comment: Well, something is definitely running on port 8080 if you get `"Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated` error. Try shutting that something down and the commands I've provided will work. I've tested them myself and there are no errors.

Comment: Well, one of your containers is clearly bound to port 8080. `c6a394453de4        node:10.15-stretch   "node"                   2 hours ago         Up 50 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                     alarm_node_1     
`

Comment: It's normal. It's should be bound to 8080... Are you proposing to use a different port ?

Comment: As far as I can see your issue is that you run `docker-compose run node bash` and it does not share port 8080 between node container and the host. I've provided an answer that allows you to run the container which shares the port properly.

Comment: read my last edit. The command to use is ```docker-compose exec node bash```